# Collatz conjecture in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, collatz

everyone!
I'm trying to solve this for school. I need to count how many steps it takes to come from any positive integer down to 1. And I'm supposed to use TypeScript.
The Collatz Conjecture or 3x+1 problem can be summarized as follows:
Take any positive integer n. If n is even, divide n by 2 to get n / 2. If n is odd, multiply n by 3 and add 1 to get 3n + 1. Repeat the process indefinitely. The conjecture states that no matter which number you start with, you will always reach 1 eventually.
Here is my guess of code:

```
function steps(n: number) {
    let counter: number = 0;
    if (n > 0 && Number.isInteger(n)) {
        while (n !== 1) {
            if (n % 2 === 0) {                                      
                n = n / 2; 
                counter++;
            } else if (n % 2 !== 0) {
                n = (n * 3) + 1;
                counter++;
            }
            return counter;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('Only positive whole numbers are allowed');
    }
}
```

I wanted my code as transparent as possible, that's why I might be writing too much code. Don't mind that.

Comment: does it work? If yes, please consider posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. We only fix the codez here, not review them ;)

Comment: Hi! No, it does not work. I need a code fix.

Comment: I see. "return" is out of place.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. The return was out of place. It is supposed to be outside while loop.

```
function steps(n: number) {
    let counter: number = 0;
    if (n > 0 && Number.isInteger(n)) {
        while (n !== 1) {
            if (n % 2 === 0) {                                      
                n = n / 2; 
                counter++;
            } else if (n % 2 !== 0) {
                n = (n * 3) + 1;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Only positive numbers are allowed');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried testing this in visual studio code why didnt it work?

```
function steps(n: number) {
let counter: number = 0;
if (n > 0 && Number.isInteger(n)) {
    while (n !== 1) {
        if (n % 2 === 0) {                                      
            n = n / 2; 
            counter++;
        } else if (n % 2 !== 0) {
            n = (n * 3) + 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
} else {
    throw new Error('Only positive numbers are allowed');
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't use `Post Answer` to ask a question. Use the [`Ask Question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include these details as well as a link back to this question for context. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30348509)

Comment: counter needs to be initialized with 1 for this to work in JS

Answer (score 0):

- Math problem that is never solved  : Collatz conjecture or 3x+1
- It will end up to 4-2-1 loop and its never ending
- Apply only two rules
- if the number is odd multiply by 3 and add 1
- if the number is even divide by 2
- It will eventually end up on 4-2-1 loop even if the number is quadrillionth of 2^68

  const collatz_conjecture = (number) => {

  ```
   setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(`Number: ${number}`);            
       if (number % 2 === 0) {
           //even
           console.log(`Number is even: ${number} - dividing by 2`);            
           number = (number / 2);
       } else {
           //odd
           console.log(`Number is odd: ${number} - multiplying by 3 and than adding 1`);
           number = (number * 3) + 1;
       }

       collatz_conjecture(number);

   }, 3 * 1000); // 3 seconds delay
  ```

  };

  collatz_conjecture(10);